# Why are the id's different when they both print out the same value?

Tags: python

I have two sets of code in python

```
one_set = set()
one_set.add("a")
two_set = one_set

print(id(one_set))
print(id(two_set))
```

After this code is printed, the id's appear to be the same

```
oneset = set()
oneset.add("a")
twoset = oneset.copy()

print(id(oneset))
print(id(twoset))
```

but when this code is printed, when you print out both of their id's, it is different.
Why does the first set of code have the same id's and the second set have different id's, even though they both print the same value "a".

Comment: Do you understand what the `id` function is? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id

Comment: The ids don't "appear" to be the same; they *are* the same, because the names `one_set` and `two_set` refer to the exact same `set` object in your first example. In the second, they don't.

Comment: Obligatory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "aliasing". In your first code, when you do:

```
two_set = one_set
```

you are calling `one_set` with another name: `two_set`. So, if both are the same object, the `id` will be the same.

In the second case, you copy the object. Then, `one_set` and `two_set` will be different objects, having different `id` value (that is, a different memory address).

Answer (score 1):

Each object in Python has it's unique id.

When you do

```py
two_set = one_set
```

You're not creating a new object. You're telling python to give another name to the same object, a `reference`.

To prove that, if you do

```py
two_set.add("b")
```

and print `one_set`, `one_set` will have "a" and "b" as values.

However, when you use a `copy()` function, python will create a new object, copy the old object's values into the new object.

and if you do

```py
two_set.add("b")
```

it won't affect `one_set`.

`one_set` and `two_set` are now completely independant objects.